# How to send data from DialogFragment to DialogFragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a problem with sending data from fragment to fragment. I have `DialogFragment` named `fmonday`, it is Viewpager's fragment.

I call other `DialogFragment`, named `AlertDFragment` to add some data to my fragment. I can read the data from spinner, it's working good.

Now I need to send one variable, type `string`, from `AlertDFragment` to `fmonday`.

Here is the code of `fmonday`:

```
public class fmonday extends DialogFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

DB db;
Button button12;
DialogFragment dlg1;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dlg1 = new AlertDFragment();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fmonday, container, false);

    button12 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button12);
    button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            dlg1.show(getFragmentManager(), "dlg1");

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

And code of `AlertDFragment`:

```
 public class AlertDFragment extends DialogFragment {
 Spinner spin;
 DB db;
 String string1;
 Button button13;
 private String namestr;
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View fdfS = li.inflate(R.layout.fdf, null);
    adb.setView(fdfS);
    spin=(Spinner)fdfS.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    db = new DB(getActivity());
    db.open();
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemClicked());
    loadSpinnerData();
    button13 = (Button) fdfS.findViewById(R.id.button13);
    button13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Clicked : " +
                    string1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });
    return adb.create();
}
```

I can't find the way to send this `string1` variable to my `fmonday` DialogFragment, because simple `intent` doesn't work with non-activity things. Also read some advices about `bundle`, but couldn't find out how to work with it.

Thanks

**UPDATE**
`fmonday`:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    dlg1 = new AlertDFragment();
    string1 =  getArguments().getString("latitude");
}
```

`AlertDFragment`:

```
  public class AlertDFragment extends DialogFragment {
  Spinner spin;
  DB db;
  String string1;
  Button button13;
  private String namestr;
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    View fdfS = li.inflate(R.layout.fdf, null);
    adb.setView(fdfS);
    spin=(Spinner)fdfS.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    db = new DB(getActivity());
    db.open();
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnSpinnerItemClicked());
    loadSpinnerData();
    button13 = (Button) fdfS.findViewById(R.id.button13);
    button13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Clicked : " +
                    string1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("latitude", string1);
            fmonday alertdfragment= new fmonday();
            alertdfragment.setArguments(bundle);
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });
    return adb.create();
}
```

Comment: You can write a getter for`string1` and then you can just access it via dlg1 as in `dlg1.getstring1()`.

Comment: Create a custom event listener for sharing data between both Fragments

Answer (score 0):

**To Set Data:**

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("latitude", latitude);
MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
mapFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

**To Get Data**

```
String latitude =  getArguments().getString("latitude")
```

Comment: >  Error:(43, 17) error: cannot find symbol class MapFragment. 

How to initialize MapFragment? Or it is like my `AlertDFragment`?

Comment: It is just a sample code I have given, you need to use your AlertDFragment and fmonday fragment.

Comment: i don't know why, maybe i wrote something wrong, but it's not working.

Comment: Are you calling getArguments() in onCreateDialog() method?

Comment: Yes, if i type getArguements() in some other place it shows error message

Comment: updated. Error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Answer (score 0):

You can crate a setter to your second dialogFragment ex:

```
public void setSmth(String value)
{
     this.myData = value;
}
```

, than on your first dialog

```
DialogFragment dlg1 = new AlertDFragment();
dlg1.setSmth(your data here);
```

before showing the second one;

Comment: So this is setter to send data from first fragment to dialogFragment? I would like to do it by the other way, from `AlertDFragment` to `fmonday`. Like when `onDismiss();` called, it supposed to send some variables to `fmonday` from dialog.